# Missing a note in the Notes app

Tags: icloud, notes.app

Here's the issue I'm faced with:

[image]

Notice the "Bookmarks -2" in Inoreader's share view and the lack of that note in the Notes app.

I have only one iCloud account associated with the Notes app and I don't have local storage enabled. No backups either.

I created that note an hour before taking the screenshot, it was visible in the notes app with content in it. I had been adding content to it for about an hour when it just disappeared.

It's been a few hours so it's not like it just hasn't synced.

I checked the catch-all folders and recently deleted folder. It's not visible via the notes app.

Where is it?

Comment: What is Inoreader and how does that relate to Apple's Notes app?  Have you reached out to that app's developer to ask about this?

Comment: Inoreader is an rss reader. However, the currently missing Note was visible in the Notes app beforehand so it's a Notes app issues, not Inoreader's.

Comment: @fsb Inoreader in the screenshot is showing Notes app share extension therefore directly relating to the Notes app, and so this would be unrelated to Inoreader and its developer.

Comment: Have you logged into iCloud.com to see if the missing note is there?

Comment: I have, it's not.